# Unable to update foreign key column of parent table from child table?

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints, ddl, dml

I have two below table orders and cart -

```
CREATE TABLE order_details (
order_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
cust_id INT NOT NULL,
cart_id INT,
payment_id INT NOT NULL,
payment_date DATE,
order_date DATE NOT NULL,
ship_date DATE,
ship_method VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
fullfillment_date DATE,
cancellation_date DATE,
return_date DATE,
FOREIGN KEY(cart_id) REFERENCES cart(cart_id) on update cascade;
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE cart (
cart_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
order_id INT NOT NULL,
product_id INT,
quantity INT NOT NULL,
discount INT,
FOREIGN KEY(order_id) REFERENCES order_details(order_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Now when i insert value to both table in the same order, the cart_id column from order_details returns null only

```
begin transaction;
INSERT INTO order_details VALUES 
(1000001,1001,NULL,100001,'2019-12-20','2019-12-20','2019-12-20','FedEx Ground','2019-12-24',NULL,NULL),
(1000002,1001,NULL,100001,'2020-2-1','2020-2-1','2020-2-1','FedEx Ground','2020-3-4',NULL,'2020-3-8'),
(1000003,1001,NULL,100001,'2020-3-1','2020-3-1','2020-3-1','FedEx Ground','2020-3-5', NULL, NULL),      
(1000004,1002,NULL,100002,'2019-4-1','2019-4-1','2019-4-1','UPS Next Day','2019-4-5',NULL,NULL),        
(1000005,1003,NULL,100003,'2019-5-7','2019-5-7','2019-5-7','USPS Media Mail','2019-5-11',NULL,NULL),        
(1000006,1004,NULL,100004,'2019-3-8','2019-3-8','2019-3-8','USPS Media Mail','2019-3-15','2019-3-15','2019-3-20'),
(1000007,1005,NULL,100005,'2020-5-20','2020-5-20','2020-5-20','USPS Registered Mail',NULL, NULL,NULL);
COMMIT;
```

```
begin transaction;
insert into cart values (1000011,1000001,NULL,1,NULL),
(1000012,1000002,NULL,1,NULL),  
(1000013,1000003,NULL,1,NULL),  
(1000014,1000004,NULL,1,NULL),  
(1000015,1000005,NULL,1,NULL),  
(1000016,1000006,NULL,1,NULL),  
(1000017,1000007,NULL,1,NULL);
COMMIT;
```

But i am expecting to see value for cart_id populating in order_details table, but it return null

```
select * from order_details ;
```

What is the exact solution to this?

Comment: nothing populates foreign keys automatically. How is it supposed to know which foreign key value to use?

Comment: You've created a chicken-and-egg relationship. Presumably you also have customers who want to order something. But they can't order anything without a cart, and they can't have a cart when they have no orders (yet). So which comes first, the order or the cart?

Comment: Also, it is not good practice to assume the order of columns when running an insert/update statement. You should always list the columns explicitly

Comment: So what is the right model to get data sequentially  in OLAP system for eg. i dont have previous experience in modelling honestly

Comment: The right model is one where you don't have circular FK references e.g. A references B references A because, as you have found, you can't insert data into either table (and your model can't actually make business sense, either). Apart from this generic statement, no-one on this site can tell you what the right model for you is because no-one knows what you are trying to model, the business requirements that are driving your model, etc.